# How to import js code locally to vue component

Tags: vue.js

I want to use the quill editor inside a vue component without installing the npm package (causes some problems). So I'd like to use the code from the cdn locally

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quill@2.0.0-rc.2/dist/quill.js
```

How would I import it correctly inside a vue component?
Just copying the code to a file and calling

`import Quill from "../../services/quill/quill.js"`

or

`import { Quill } from "../../services/quill/quill.js"`

throws the error `no export named default...`

Comment: "causes some problems" - you probably need to address them then. It's unknown what's your setup and why there could be an error. It's unclear how the ""../../services/" part is related, you say that you want to load it from CDN

Comment: I don't want to load it from the cdn. I copied the code from the cdn and stored it locally and just want to import it for usage. The npm package causes problems related with the shadow dom.

Comment: How? You're supposed to get the same file in node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js as in copied quill.js. The error is specific to your setup, which is again, unknown. Generally you'd do `import Quill from "quill/dist/quill.js"` and it's expected to work because it's UMD module that's translated to ESM default export in a regular vue project with build tools

Comment: I'm using a vue custom component, so the code is wrapped inside a shadow dom. In another file (no vue) I'm already using the quill.js file without the npm package and just want to import it to the vue component and it's not working like I tried to. That's why I ask how it'd be done properly.

Comment: Have you looked in the docs? [Quill documentation - npm](https://quilljs.com/docs/installation#npm)

Comment: Then load it globally with <script> like you likely already did and stick to using window.Quill to use the same Quill copy in all scripts. Depending on the setup you can make it a fake import for better maintenance, like https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/3744

Comment: @PeterPointer I did - I also tried it in a vue component without being a custom element. Then it seems to work better. So the problem must be the custom elements shadow dom. That's why I want to import it locally to compare.